# WPF Textblock в 2 слоя

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Я наложил один `Textblock` поверх другого для создания нужной мне анимации, но заметил что края нижнего чуть видно из под верхнего:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выглядит нижний слой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это выделение абсолютно все портит, можно ли от него как-нибудь избавиться?

Код:

```
    <TextBlock FontSize="120"
               Width="255"
               Height="95"
               x:Name="Serv1"
               FontFamily="Fonts/#TT Commons Bold"
               Margin="80,217,0,0"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF7C127B" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF482A7B" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </TextBlock.Foreground>
        So
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Width="{Binding ElementName=Serv1, Path=Width}"
               Height="{Binding ElementName=Serv1, Path=Height}"
               FontSize="{Binding ElementName=Serv1, Path=FontSize}" 
               FontFamily="{Binding ElementName=Serv1, Path=FontFamily}"
               Text="{Binding ElementName=Serv1, Path=Text}"
               Margin="{Binding ElementName=Serv1, Path=Margin}" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop x:Name="WhiteOffset" Color="#211e23"/>
                <GradientStop x:Name="GrayOffset" Color="Transparent"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </TextBlock.Foreground>
        <TextBlock.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="WhiteOffset" From="1" To="0.5" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="GrayOffset" From="1" To="0.5" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </TextBlock.Triggers>
    </TextBlock>
```

Comment: Я уверен, вам не нужно наложение совсем. Вы можете анимировать цвет. А вообще во всем виноват антиалиасинг (сглаживание шрифта), границы букв полупрозрачные, от него конечно можно избавиться, но тогда края букв будут выглядеть грубо, так как будут видны пиксели. Можете подробнее рассказать, какой эффект вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: Мне нужно, что бы градиент `Textblock.Foreground` был по бокам, то биж справа и слева. Но что бы он поднимался вверх будто бы наливают сок в кружку.

Comment: Снизу вверх понятно, а по бокам - это как? Быть может [`RadialGradient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-paint-an-area-with-a-radial-gradient?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) нужен? Можете показать визуальный пример такой анимации?

Comment: Кажется понял, просто плавная заливка снизу вверх анимацией, но текстура заливки с градиентом, так? Если да, то до меня дошло, попробую чуть позже реализовать, покажу пример.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам не нужно наложение двух `TextBlock`. Достаточно поместить текст в `Grid` с `OpacityMask`, определяемую градиентом заливки, и анимировать этот градиент.

Как-то так у меня получилось:

```xml
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5">
    <Grid.OpacityMask>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1" >
            <GradientStop x:Name="GradientMask" Offset="0.5" Color="Transparent" />
            <GradientStop Offset="{Binding Offset, ElementName=GradientMask}" Color="White" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.OpacityMask>
    <TextBlock FontSize="120" FontFamily="Fonts/#TT Commons Bold" Text="So">
        <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF7C127B" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF482A7B" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </TextBlock.Foreground>
        <TextBlock.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="GradientMask" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </TextBlock.Triggers>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]